# How to remove redundant elements in a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt

I'm struggling to find a safe solution (fear of iterator invalidation) to erase some elements in a `QStringList`:

```
static QStringList s_listDistantDirs;
```

I want to erase an element `CurrentElement` if its length is superior to the other element `OtherElement` and if `OtherElement` is equal to `CurrentElement.mid(OtherElement.length())`.

In other words, I want to erase sub directories of an existent directory in the list.

I tried to use `QMutableListIterator<QString>` but I don't know how to use it properly to nest a loop.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me, do you want to erase the sub-directories of a particular directory (that is specified externally to the list itself), or do you want to go through the light and remove all directories that are sub-directories of any other path that is also in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
static QStringList s_listDistantDirs;
//...
QStringListIterator it(s_listDistantDirs);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    QString& otherElement = it.next().value();
    // QMutableStringListIterator is just a typedef for QMutableIterator<QString>
    QMutableStringListIterator mit(s_listDistantDirs);
    while(mit.hasNext()) {
        QString& currentElement = mit.next().value();
        if (currentElement.length() > otherElement.length()
            && currentElement.startsWith(otherElement))
                mit.remove(); // this will not invalidate `it`!
    }
}
```

As per [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistiterator.html):

> Multiple iterators can be used on the same list. If the list is modified while a QListIterator is active, the QListIterator will continue iterating over the original list, ignoring the modified copy.

But it's quite inefficient and at this point it would be better to just use some data structure, like prefix tree.

Comment: I changed QStringListIterator by the mutable version and removed .value() (this member doesn't exist) and it work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, I want to erase sub directories of an existent directory in the list.

If the existent directory is known in advance, you can use [QStringList::filter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#filter-2) and a regex like this:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
  QString myPath("/my/path/");
  QRegularExpression re("^(?!" + myPath + ")");
  QStringList list = (QStringList()
    << "/my/path/a"
    << "/my/path/b"
    << "/some/other/path/c"
    << "/my/path/d");
  for(auto &l: list.filter(re)) {
    qDebug() << l;
  }
}
```